# Multiple Interfaces to a Class in C++

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism

I have three classes that interact as follows. `Class A` contains a private member of type `Class B`. It also contains a method to which an object of type `ClassC` is passed. This method then calls a method on `ClassC`, passing to it a particular interface (`ClassBInterface1`) of its member of type `ClassB`:

```
 ClassA
 {
     void Foo(ClassC ObjectC)
     {
         ObjectC.Bar((ClassBInterface1) ObjectB);
     }
     ClassB ObjectB;
 }
```

My question is: `ClassA` does not need to access the methods of `ClassB` defined in `Interface1`. Therefore, in my view, it would be more elegant if the member of `ClassA` was of type `ClassBInterface2`, rather than `ClassB`. Is it possible to do this, while still passing B to C under `Interface1`?

The only way I can think of is to typecast `ClassBInterface2` to `ClassB` and back to `ClassBInterface1` in the Bar method in `ClassA`.

Is this the best way to do it? Or should I just leave it as it is?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: what is a class interface in your context :s ? My best guess is you're over-designing but this question is so abstract it's hard to answer.

Comment: Don't cast an interface type into another, that defeats the purpose of independence, I recommend leaving it as it is, or keeping 2 references of both interfaces types to the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `ObjectB` as a `ClassBInterface2` it won't be possible to convert it to `ClassBInterface1` at runtime because it's internal structure won't be known.

Your way is the best one to do it but you can do a little modification. You don't need to do a explicit cast from `ClassB` to `ClassBInterface1` while calling `ObjectC.Bar` because the compiler will do it for you.

If `class B` is defined as follows:

```
ClassB : public ClassBInterface1, ClassBInterface2
{

  /*Class methods and attributes*/

}
```

you can just do the following while calling the Bar function on the ObjectC (assuming `objectB` is defined as `ClassB`)

```
ObjectC.Bar(ObjectB);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a great feature for this called "forward declarations". Basically, for any parts of your code that don't need to know the details of a class, you can simply pass around a reference. Only when you want to call member methods (including constructors and destructors) do you need to have the full class definition.

```
#include "ClassC.h"
class ClassB;

class ClassA
{
public:
    void foo(ClassC& objectC)
    {
       objectC.bar(_objectB);
    }

protected:
    ClassB& _objectB;
};
```

Note that we include a header for ClassC because we need to call one of his methods.

Note that we forward declare ClassB and only hold a reference because we don't really care what he is.

Note finally that ClassA can't be instantiated currently, because somehow the reference to _objectB has to be set to something. For example, a constructor:

```
public ClassA(ClassB& objectB)
    : _objectB(objectB)
{}
```

ClassA now only holds on to whatever reference was given to him on construction.

Based on your use of the term "interface" in your question, I assume you may have a class hierarchy. This answer can easily be extended to such a hierarchy. But the important point here is that concrete types always require a class definition, while simple reference object only require a forward declaration.